# How to pop out non-matching column names in a series of csv files?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, sapply, rbind

I am reading multiple csv files (20 files) and finally creating one dataframe. Though I manually checked by eye, the column names were same. However, for some reason I get the below error.

> Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
>     names do not match previous names

This is the code that I wrote

```
fnames <- list.files("C:/Users/code",pattern='^La') # getting all the files from directory. Update it as required
csv <- lapply(fnames,read.csv)  # reading all the files
source_DF <- do.call(rbind, lapply(csv, '[', 1:8)) # This is the line where it throws error
```

Please note that I use `1:8` because some times R reads uneven number of columns. For example, all my csv files only has 8 columns but when it reads, sometimes it has 12 and some has even 50. So, to avoid that I have got `1:8`. Any other approach to read first 8 columns is also welcome

How can I find out which of the csv file has this naming issue and what are the columns that is causing this issue?

Any help to resolve this error would really be helpful

Comment: For future reference: it would be helpful to include a reproducible example, as well as expected output, in order for others to be able to answer your question accurately.

Comment: Sure. But in this case, other than my code, I wasn't sure how to share an example

Comment: The core of the problem is that you have a list of data frames, some of which have different names: simply create some fake data like that. A good read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4550695

Comment: Thank you. Will follow that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to check it would be to subset first 8 columns from each dataframe, get the common names present in all the dataframe, then use `setdiff` to find out if there is any mismatch of column names

```
list_df <- lapply(csv, '[', 1:8)
cols <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(list_df, names))
lapply(list_df, function(x) setdiff(names(x), cols))
```

If all your column names are the same you should get `character(0)` as output for each dataframe. If there is any mismatch `setdiff` will display the name of the column.

Also another hint to check would be is `length(cols)` 8 ?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a loop here, and check each set of names against the previous ones:

```r
dfs <- list(
  data.frame(foo = 1, bar = 2),
  data.frame(foo = 2, bar = 2),
  data.frame(foo = 3, baz = 2),
  data.frame(foo = 4, bar = 2)
)

for (i in seq_len(length(dfs) - 1)) {
  different <- names(dfs[[i]]) != names(dfs[[i + 1]])
  if (any(different)) {
    message("Names of column(s) ", paste(which(different), collapse = ", "),
            " in data frame ", i + 1, " differ from the previous ones.")
  }
}
#> Names of column(s) 2 in data frame 3 differ from the previous ones.
#> Names of column(s) 2 in data frame 4 differ from the previous ones.
```

Or, if you just wanted to store the mismatches:

```r
mismatches <- list(integer())
for (i in seq_len(length(dfs) - 1)) {
  different <- names(dfs[[i]]) != names(dfs[[i + 1]])
  mismatches[[i + 1]] <- which(different)
}

str(mismatches)
#> List of 4
#>  $ : int(0) 
#>  $ : int(0) 
#>  $ : int 2
#>  $ : int 2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9000)</sup>

Comment: But isn't there any other way to do this? I have more than 20 dataframes and each df has more than 30 columns.. Example was 8 though

Comment: I don't see what the number of data frames or columns has to do with this? The solution is the same -- this explicitly answers your question of which files have differing names, and which columns are the ones that differ. If you wanted to compute on that information, you'd just also save it for each iteration.

Comment: The difference between my answer and @ronakshah's is the "source of truth": mine takes the previous names as the "correct" ones, which matches what causes the `rbind()` error, while theirs takes the set of names that occur in all data frames: meaning that if there are any differing names anywhere, you'll get a "mismatch" for _all_ data frames.